# Create list from data.frame

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, riverplot

I'm trying to produce a sankey-plot using the package `riverplot` in `R`. In order to do that I need to create a riverplot object. Following the vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverplot/riverplot.pdf) this seems quite straightforward. Unfortunately, it is not.

I get the an error message and am unable to identify why. Can anyone help?

```
install.packages("riverplot")
library(riverplot)

edges <- data.frame(N1=rep("SP", 8), 
                  N2=c("AL", "CVP", "EVP", "FDP", "GPS", "glp", "SVP", "SP"),
                  Value=c(77,1,1,1,20,9,1,103))

nodes <- data.frame(ID=c("SP", "AL", "CVP", "EVP", "FDP", "GPS", "glp", "SVP", "SP"),
                  x=c(1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

r.file <- makeRiver(nodes, edges)

Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘SP’
```

Of course `row.names(edges) <- NULL` and `row.names(nodes) <- NULL` don't solve the problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: You have two nodes named `SP` in your nodes dataframe and that is not allowed. All the nodes have to have a unique name.

Comment: How stupid of me. Thanks for translating the error message to me :-)

Comment: Try `plot(makeRiver(nodes[!duplicated(nodes$ID),], edges))`